# Working with Windows Registry from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, registry

my .net app needs to store some persistent data and since it is possible that it runs in an environment where it cant write to disk, i would like to use the registry for it.

1. are there any conventions about the path where an application is writing to?
2. are there any tools or libraries that make reading and writing the registry from .net more convenient? i need to mostly write simple datatypes and datastructures like lists.
3. any other best practices or tips & tricks that should be know when working with the registry?

Comment: Rather than using the registry, I recommend persisting data to a file in the [AppData](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/what-appdata-folder) folder.  To get the AppData path use [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx) with the [SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) ApplicationData or LocalApplicationData.  Create a folder to store application data using the convention <AppData>\<company>\<application>.  The user should have read write access to AppData.

Comment: that's what i did so far, but due to the special environment i cant rely that this is always read/writeable thats why i use the registry now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing to the registry is a little frowned on nowadays, however if you must:

Put settings for the current user in: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Your Company\Your App

Put settings for all users in: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Your Company\Your App

Use the Registry class in the .NET framework to read and write registry keys and values:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.110).aspx